# VisualVM connection to Tomcat hosted on Docker

Tags: tomcat, docker, jmx, visualvm

I'm trying to configure a JMX connection from VisualVM to a Tomcat hosted on a remote Docker machine :

```
locahost with VisualVM --> server with docker (192.168.23.8) --> Tomcat container
```

My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM centos:centos6

RUN yum upgrade -y \
  &&  yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk \
  &&  yum -y install tar \
  && yum clean all

COPY apache-tomcat-7.0.64.tar.gz /tmp/
RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat
RUN tar -xzvf /tmp/apache-tomcat-7.0.64.tar.gz --directory /opt/tomcat/ --strip 1
RUN rm /tmp/apache-tomcat-7.0.64.tar.gz

COPY catalina-jmx-remote.jar /opt/tomcat/lib/
COPY setenv.sh /opt/tomcat/bin/
COPY server.xml /opt/tomcat/conf/

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9090
EXPOSE 9091

CMD /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start && tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

With bin/setenv.sh file (where 192.168.23.8 is my host ip) :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.23.8"
```

With original conf/server.xml where I added the following listener :

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" 
          rmiRegistryPortPlatform="9090" rmiServerPortPlatform="9091" />
```

And catalina-jmx-remote.jar which has been found in 7.0.64 extras libs.

Every port are opened between localhost and the docker server and my ports are correctly exposed :

```
Ports: [
{
IP: "0.0.0.0",
PrivatePort: 9091,
PublicPort: 9091,
Type: "tcp"
},
{
IP: "0.0.0.0",
PrivatePort: 9090,
PublicPort: 9090,
Type: "tcp"
},
{
IP: "0.0.0.0",
PrivatePort: 8080,
PublicPort: 33284,
Type: "tcp"
}
]
```

And the Tomcat logs are :

```
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
Oct 26, 2015 8:36:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
Oct 26, 2015 8:36:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
Oct 26, 2015 8:36:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.23.8
...
Oct 26, 2015 8:36:53 AM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener createServer
INFO: The JMX Remote Listener has configured the registry on port 9090 and the server on port 9091 for the Platform server
```

But when I open a new JMX connection on VisualVM, I got the following error :

```
Cannot connect to 192.168.23.8:9090 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.23.8:9090/jmxrmi
```

Any idea to resolve the problem?

Comment: How do you run the Docker container?

Comment: Where does the JSON array of ports come from? I'm wondering if the ports are correctly published - what do you get if you run `docker ports` on the container?

Comment: The JSON array comes from the REST API : (...:2375/containers/json). With docker port, I get : 8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:33284
9090/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9090
9091/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9091

Comment: I run the Docker container with a Maven plugin. It is equivalent to : docker run -itd -p 9090:9090 -p 9091:9091...

Comment: And can you access that port from the Docker host?

Comment: "telnet localhost 9090" and "telnet localhost 9091" answer correctly. Works also from the client machine.

Comment: The client machine being the one with VisualVM? So it's something to do with JMX/Tomcat then? Are you sure you've correctly forwarded all the ports you need? Why is 8080 being forwarded to 33284?

Comment: Yep the client machine is the one with VisualVM. I think I only need 9090 and 9091 for jmx but I'm not sure. Port 8080 is forwarded to a dynamic port in order to have several apps, but for the moment there is only this app.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue; do you remember if/how you ever resolved this?